# VSS to SVN- How to Checkout but do not get local copy

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am transitioning from VSS to SVN using Tortoise and I cannot figure out how to checkout a project that I created and not over write my local copy. VSS lets you checkout without overriding your local copy. I searched around and could not find the answer.

Comment: I'm nut sure I understand your question because I'm not familiar with VSS although I have years of experience with SVN. Maybe you are looking for things that are different in SVN?

If you have a local copy then it was obtained through a checkout.

Comment: VSS lets you checkout a file and not pull a local copy to your harddrive. So if you have a file that you modified, but was not checked out you could check it out and leave the local copy instead of pulling from the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check out into an existing folder, Subversion will **not** overwrite your existing files. Instead it will mark them as modified already after the checkout is finished.

Comment: I will give that a try. I assumed that since it prompts with the warning that the directory is not empty that it would over write what was there.

Comment: Funny thing happend when I tried to do that. It failed because the last time I checked out this particular project it was with SVN version 1.6 and I tried to check it out with SVN 1.7.1 I think and it said it could not because it is incompatible from 1.6. So, I went in and erased all the _svn directories, and checked it out. None of the files were over written and the ones different were marked as modified as you stated. So thank you for the help.

Comment: A side question would be is what I did to make it compatible with version 1.7.1 the only way to make it recognize the project if SVN or Tortoise are upgraded? I would have assumed some backward compatibility there. Again, Thanks for the help.

Comment: svn 1.7 uses a completely new working copy format and therefore a manual upgrade is necessary. A fresh checkout is however recommended since the upgrade process isn't as stable as other functions in the svn lib.

Comment: Just make sure you backup your folder first!

Answer (score 2):

The best bet with SVN, in that case, is to simply checkout a new copy to a new folder that you create.

Answer (score 1):

You need checkout to empty folder and after override received files by yours.

Comment: I was hoping I would not have to copy files back and forth. It seems this is the only way to do what I want. Thanks.